# Programmatically check whether employee/user left the orgnization

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, azure-ad

We have sharepoint online site. We have one console application written in CSOM which send emails to users. We want to exclude users who left the orgnization.

How can we identify user left the orgnization?

- Is there any way using CSOM or REST API?
- Is there any user profile property which give this information?
- Is there any Azure AD property which give this information?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graph API to check if the user is enabled in Azure AD (or basically any other property from the AAD including custom properties). This endpoint gets all users:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=accountEnabled,DisplayName,mail
```

If you want to get all properties of the users in AAD just call the beta endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users
```

If your organization has any custom properties that is better to use in your situation you will get them in this endpoint.

To use the Graph API you would need to register your console application in AAD. But if you already interact with SharePoint this might be already be the case and you just need to assign it graph permissions (User.Read.All).